# difference between q=word1 word2 and q="word1 word2" in Solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene

Can someone please tell me what is the difference between:

```
q=word1 word2
```

and

```
q="word1 word2"
```

I'm trying to match a keyword "word1 word2" (yes, my keyword can have whitespaces) that is analyzed with `KeywordTokenizerFactory` and it seems it only works when I add the quotes in the query.

By the way I use Solr extended Dismax, don't know if this matters.
The syntax is then:

```
q="some text"&qf=KeywordField&qf=FrenchtextField
```

---

**Edit:**

The problem I have with quotes is that I have another field that contains fulltexte (analysis is basic and close to FrenchAnalyzer, including a lowercase filter)

I have 'HelloWorld' text indexed, and I can find it back with q=helloWoRLD but not with q="helloWoRLD": this unit test is broken since I added quotes in all my queries. I don't understand what is the difference between q=helloWoRLD and q="helloWoRLD" since it would still be 1 term search right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene query syntax uses spaces to separate terms so you are performing a search for "word1" in the field "q" and "word2" but with no specified field (I'm not sure how lucene behaves when no field is specified).

- If you want to search for the string "word1 word2" (consecutive words) in the field q then you will have to use quotes i.e. q="word1 word2"
- If you want to search for records which contain both of these words (non-consecutive) then you can search for "q=word1 AND q=word2"

I don't quite follow your hello world problem so can't comment on that. Hope this helps

Comment: I use eDismax so I don't need to specify the fields on the q= attribute: check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax

Comment: see my edit please I try to be more clear about the helloWoRLD part

Comment: thanks for the update... I don't think I can be any more help here as I'm not familiar with Dismax. It sounds like the problem could be with dismax or your analyser but I'm just guessing